# Apache don't restart with new Vhost *:443

Tags: apache, https, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I'm trying to add a virtual host on my EC2 centos instance.
I added mod24_ssl, and my certificates.

But when I try to add a new virtual host apache don't want to restart.
I just copy paste a working vhost and change port :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/

    ErrorLog /var/www/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/

    ErrorLog /var/www/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working fine without the second virtual host, but not when I Add it.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Is there a another virtual host configuration on that port? You can't do name based virtual hosting for SSL

Comment: @datasage - You can do name based for vhosting for SSL but it depends on the version of SSL library you're using, the browser performing the request etc. More trouble than it's worth. I think you're right with regards to a duplicate host somewhere.

Comment: @user227450 - is that the sum total of the vhost configuration you're trying? If so, you're not specifying any certs to use, their cyphers etc. Check the `ssl.conf` file for details on what goes where. To be honest, adapt that file with your own certs and `DocumentRoot` setting and it should work OK

Comment: Thank you all, It's a copie of another host, i just have change the port as you can see. I tried with or without the cert, but with the same effect, apache does'nt want to restart. I need to remove the ServerName ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a conflict with the default 443 vhost of amazone EC2.

The things to know is that a default ssl virtual host is already set in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

that's all